# execute sql command via jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

so the page generate a unique code after the countdown ends then redirecting to another page .
before redirecting i want to insert that code in the databasae .. or after the click function , how can i do that ? is there a way to run a sql command via jquery ?

```
   $(".play").click(function(){
   var sec = 10
   var timer = setInterval(function() { 
   $('.slide span#sec').text(sec--);
   if (sec == -1) {
          $("#sub").click(); //submit the data
      clearInterval(timer);
   } 
   }, 1000);
   });


<form method="post" action="next.php?id=<?echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="str_generator" value="<?php echo "$str_generator" ?>"/>
<input type="submit" id="sub" name="submit" style="display:none" ></input>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an AJAX call which would execute the query and redirect the user when you get the success response from the AJAX call.

Comment: i want to execute the query right after the user clicks on a div and the countdown ends .. my point is that i don't want from any visitor to insert that code to the database , only the visitors who clicks on a div

Comment: This is getting into security. You can have the system create a token that it can validate and check for that token as part of the AJAX request.